# New to SQL Server looking for assistance for a datetime conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my first submission on Stack Overflow, and I am open to any suggestions on structuring my questions.

I am new to SQL Server, and I have a line of code I that I don't understand.

Can someone please explain this?

```
declare @prior_year datetime = convert(date, '12/31/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1))
```

Comment: formatting of your question is great. You're welcome;)

Answer (score 3):

This is a problematic way to determine the last day of the year before the date(time) stored in some variable.

```
convert(date, '12/31/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1))
```

## In English, working outward:

1. ```
      datepart(yy, @start_date)
   ```

   > **Tell me the year of the variable @start_date.** 
   > This is poor form because, if we mean year, we should spell out `YEAR` (see "Date Parts" in [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)). I said this already once today, but this is just laziness, it's like "I'm going to type just enough characters to avoid an unexpected result, but not enough characters to make my intent clear." Worse is `YYYY`, which I see often - you have a choice between `YYYY` and `YEAR`, why not type the one that's actually a word?
2. ```
      datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1
    --------------------------- ^^^
   ```

   > **Subtract one from that year.**
   > I don't have any issues here, but it may be clearer to use an explicit `DATEADD()` against the variable *first*, and then extracting the year from that, since things like `<some date thing> - 1` can be misread as an attempt to subtract a day (also covered in the [shorthand post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) referenced above).
3. ```
      convert(varchar, datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1))
    --^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   > **Convert that explicitly to a string.**
   >
   > Also poor form here because we should always specify the *length* of variable-width data. In some cases this can lead to unexpected truncation. See [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).
4. ```
      '12/31/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1))
    --^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   > **Prefix that year with 12/31 to produce a mm/dd/yyyy string.**
   >
   > More poor form, because this then assumes the user has US English regional settings, MDY dateformat, etc. If you're going to insist on building a string that represents a date, always use a standard, unambiguous format: `YYYYMMDD`. (And FWIW `YYYY-MM-DD` **is ambiguous**, try it with `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;`). See [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).
5. ```
    convert(date, <the rest>)
   ```

   > **Converts the whole expression to a date.**

## A better solution

Ideally we should not be using strings anywhere along the line for any of this. We have built-in functions that provide all kinds of native date handling capabilities without having to worry about languages, regional settings, date format preferences, or string lengths:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@start_date) - 1, 12, 31);

-- or, more explicitly:

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, @start_date) - 1, 12, 31);
```

The other way you can think about this is that the last day of last year is the same day as the day before the first day of this year. Thinking about it in these terms can make it much easier to conceptualize when you are doing things like prior month, where determining the last day of the previous month is more tedious. Or if you are finding endpoints for range queries, because the *end* of the *current* reporting period is never as deterministic as the *start* of the *next* reporting period. [More on that here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@start_date), 1, 1));
```

Also of potential use:

- [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)
- [Simplify Date Period Calculations in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [SQL Server DateTime Best Practices](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Four short videos in this series](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9314/sql-server-date-and-time-data-type-comparison/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: Good explanation this helps me better understand how to convey a good answer. I thought I had it but this is much better. Like how you used the quotes and numbering :P

Comment: thank you for breaking this down step by step. I will check out the additional posts in your explanation, but from what you have written is pretty straightforward. Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

`declare @prior_year datetime = convert(date, '12/31/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1))`

This SQL code declares a **@prior_year** `datetime` variable that is hard coded to *12/31/*. `datepart` is used to extract the previous year from another `datetime` variable **@start_date**` that is passed in and tacks the returned value onto the end of the '12/31/' hard coded string. So; its really just a formula of 12/31/(@start_date prior year)

- So if @start_date is 8/20/2020
- You will end up with the output of 12/31/2019

  ```
   declare @start_date datetime = getdate()
   declare @prior_year datetime = convert(date, '12/31/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1))
   select @prior_year
  ```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: okay this makes sense... let's take another example: if the @start_date = 9/28/1991 then this output would be 12/31/2018 correct?

Comment: @tony_ysl No, that would return 1990. The formula takes the year from @start_date, subtracts one from it, and tacks it onto the `12/31/` prefix. So since your passing 9/28/1991, take 1991 and subtract 1.

Comment: You can run the following as a test  for 9/28/1991 `declare @start_date datetime = '9/28/1991' declare @prior_year datetime = convert(date, '12/31/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1)) select @prior_year`

Comment: @vvv4d my apologies I meant to write 12/31/2018, but thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

Reading this from the inside out:

We're first finding the year of the date using `DATEPART` and then subtracting `1` so for a value for today's date: `2020-08-18` we'd be getting an integer value of 19

```
 datepart(yy, '2020-08-18') - 1)
```

We're then using `convert` on that value to change it to a `varchar`:

`convert(varchar, 19)`

We're then using that new varchar to create a string:

`'12/31/' + '19'`

Finally we're using convert again to create a date from the string

`convert(date, '12/31/19')`

Comment: in your answer I would also add an indication that `@start_date` is a previously declared variable.

Comment: datepart is just taking the year from the @startdate variable?

Comment: @tony_ysl; yep exactly; here's more about other things you can do with this function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Tony,

For completeness please provide the definition and assignment for @start_date. Assuming the statement you provided works, it is probably defined something like

```
declare @start_date date
set @start_date = '07-01-2020'
```

Working from the inside out, we can then break the statement down like so ...

This will extract the year value

```
datepart(yy, @start_date)
```

This will subtract 1 from the @start_date year value, assuming 2020, this returns 2019

```
convert(varchar, datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1)
```

And then this will convert that to the last day of the previous year.

```
convert(date, '12/31/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, @start_date) - 1))
```

So the statement simply sets the new field to the last day of the prior year.